# Accessing published vars from ObservedObjects inside a function

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, observedobject

i have 2 classes (one for HealthKit and the other for CoreMotion) which assign values to some published variables, which I then access through my main swiftui file. My content view gets updates correctly. So far so good. Now I want to log the output of these variables to the console. I could do this directly by logging directly from the class, but the issue I have is that I need to have the output for both classes in a single line. I wrote a new function for this, but the values do not get updated. Anyone who can help me ? Is it because the function only gets called once so all parameters are always the parameters when the function got called ?

my main contentView.swift file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isActive: Bool = false
    @ObservedObject var motion = MotionManager()
    @ObservedObject var health = HealthKitManager()

    private var logger = ConsoleLogger()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Indicator(title: "X:", value: motion.rotationX)
                Indicator(title: "Y:", value: motion.rotationY)
                Indicator(title: "Z:", value: motion.rotationZ)
                Divider()
                Indicator(title: "Pitch:", value: motion.pitch)
                Indicator(title: "Roll:", value: motion.roll)
                Indicator(title: "Yaw:", value: motion.yaw)
                Divider()
                Indicator(title: "HR:", value: health.heartRateValue)
                }
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            Button(action: {
                self.isActive.toggle()
                self.isActive ? self.start() : self.stop()
            }) {
                Text(isActive ? "Stop" : "Start")
            }
            .background(isActive ? Color.green : Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }.onAppear {
            self.health.autorizeHealthKit()
        }
    }

    private func start() {
        self.motion.startMotionUpdates()
        self.health.fetchHeartRateData(quantityTypeIdentifier: .heartRate)
        self.logger.startLogging(rotationX: self.motion.rotationX, rotationY: self.motion.rotationY, rotationZ: self.motion.rotationZ, pitch: self.motion.pitch, roll: self.motion.roll, yaw: self.motion.yaw, heartRate: self.health.heartRateValue)
    }

    private func stop() {
        self.motion.stopMotionUpdates()
        self.health.stopFetchingHeartRateData()
        self.logger.stopLogging()
    }

}

struct Indicator: View {
    var title: String
    var value: Double

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title)
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("\(value)")
                .font(.footnote)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my consoleLogger.swift file

```
import Foundation
import os.log

class ConsoleLogger {

    private var timer: Timer?

    func startLogging(rotationX: Double, rotationY: Double, rotationZ: Double, pitch: Double, roll: Double, yaw: Double, heartRate: Double) {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
            os_log("Motion: %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@",
                   String(timestamp),
                   String(rotationX),
                   String(rotationY),
                   String(rotationZ),
                   String(pitch),
                   String(roll),
                   String(yaw),
                   String(heartRate)
            )
        })
    }

    func stopLogging() {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

So my timer is working, I'm seeing the output in the console every second, however all variables  (except the timestamp which is created in the class) have the initial value of 0.0. Any idea how to solve ?

Comment: adjusted. :) thanks

Comment: By the way, not relevant to the question, but everything about your `startLogging` is a Bad Smell. This bunch of values should be bundled up into a struct with a `description`, so that all your `os_log` has to do is print that struct.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the problem simply that you only call `startLogging` once with the initial set of values? You then just proceed to print that *same* set of values over and over. You are nowhere consulting the actual *data* (currently held your `motion` and `health` objects) to see what it is *now*.

Comment: Personally what I would do is use the Combine framework to subscribe to both your observed objects and use `.combineLatest` and `.throttle` to output the current data once per second at most.

Comment: yeah, probably. I'll try to find a solution for it. btw ... Can you explain what you meant with "This bunch of values should be bundled up into a struct with a description, so that all your os_log has to do is print that struct" ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to say that any more directly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to .combineLatest and .throttle. Reading into Combine now and it all starts to get clear

Comment: I've written a tutorial: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsJoiners/operatorscombinelatest.html